# How to implement one way binding in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

I want to implement one way binding in react.js.

I have **chatHistory** variable:

```
   var chatHistory = [{ Author: "Daniel Lo Nigro", Text: "Hello ReactJS.NET World!" },
      { Author: "Pete Hunt", Text: "This is one comment" },
      { Author: "Jordan Walke", Text: "This is *another* comment" }];
```

and I want react to update the **DOM** if **chatHistory** variable will change.

Here is the code I have:

```
var converter = new Showdown.converter();
var Comment = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'Comment',
    render: function () {
        var rawMarkup = converter.makeHtml(this.props.children.toString());
        return (
          React.DOM.div({ className: "comment" },
            React.DOM.h2({ className: "commentAuthor" },
              this.props.author
            ),
            React.DOM.span({ dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: rawMarkup } })
        )
      );
    }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'CommentList',
    render: function () {
        var commentNodes = chatHistory.map(function (comment) {
            return Comment({ author: comment.Author }, comment.Text);
        });
        return (
          React.DOM.div({ className: "commentList" },
            commentNodes
          )
      );
    }
});

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'CommentBox',
    render: function () {
        return (
          React.DOM.div({ className: "commentBox" },
            React.DOM.h1(null, "Comments"),
            CommentList()
          )
      );
    }
});

React.renderComponent(CommentBox(),document.getElementById('content'));
```

React change the DOM only after calling `React.renderComponent(CommentBox(),document.getElementById('content'));` and not automatically via one way binding.

How to force react to refresh DOM when **chatHistory** variable changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React has two methods which can force a re-render - forceUpdate() and setState();

setState is probably the method you'll want to use.

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

This part of the React tutorial explains using setState pretty well with dynamically updating the model data via ajax

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#fetching-from-the-server